# How to have lzo compression in hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to use lzo to compress map output but I can't run it! The version of Hadoop I used is `0.20.2`. I set:

```
conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true") 
conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.codec",
"org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec");
```

When I run the jar file in Hadoop it shows an exception that can't write map output.

Do I have to install lzo? 
What do I have to do to use lzo?

Comment: may we know the exact exception?

Answer (score 11):

LZO's licence (GPL) is incompatible with that of Hadoop (Apache) and therefore it cannot be bundled with it. One needs to install LZO separately on the cluster.

The following steps are tested on [Cloudera's Demo VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera+QuickStart+VM) (CentOS 6.2, x64) that comes with full stack of CDH 4.2.0 and CM Free Edition installed, but they should work on any Linux based on Red Hat.

The installation consists of the following steps:

- Installing LZO

  `sudo yum install lzop`

  `sudo yum install lzo-devel`
- Installing ANT

  `sudo yum install ant ant-nodeps ant-junit java-devel`
- Downloading the source

  `git clone https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo.git`
- Compiling Hadoop-LZO

  `ant compile-native tar`

  For further instructions and troubleshooting see https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo
- Copying Hapoop-LZO jar to Hadoop libs

  `sudo cp build/hadoop-lzo*.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/`
- Moving native code to Hadoop native libs

  `sudo mv build/hadoop-lzo-0.4.17-SNAPSHOT/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/`

  `cp /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libgplcompression.* /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/`

  Correct version number with the version you cloned
- When working with a real cluster (as opposed to a pseudo-cluster) you need to rsync these to the rest of the machines

  `rsync /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` to all hosts.

  You can dry run this first with -n
- Login to Cloudera Manager
- Select from Services: mapreduce1->Configuration
- Client->Compression
- Add to Compression Codecs:

  `com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec`

  `com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec`
- Search "valve"
- Add to MapReduce Service Configuration Safety Valve

  `io.compression.codec.lzo.class=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec`
  `mapred.child.env="JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/"`
- Add to MapReduce Service Environment Safety Valve

  `HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*`

That's it.

Your MarReduce jobs that use `TextInputFormat` should work seamlessly with `.lzo` files. However, if you choose to index the LZO files to make them splittable (using `com.hadoop.compression.lzo.DistributedLzoIndexer`), you will find that the indexer writes a `.index` file next to each `.lzo` file. This is a problem because your `TextInputFormat` will interpret these as part of the input. In this case you need to change your MR jobs to work with `LzoTextInputFormat`.

As of Hive,  as long as you don't index the LZO files, the change is also transparent. If you start indexing (to take advantage of a better data distribution) you will need to update the input format to `LzoTextInputFormat`. If you use partitions, you can do it per partition.

Comment: Hi, now instead of ant, requires maven for build twitter/hadoop-lzo.